# how to read a text file in java by name

Tags: java, file

i want to input the file name as file not as file.txt.How to modify this code

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the input file name: ");
        String newfile = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: What type of file you want to read?

Comment: Are you really asking "How to add .txt extension to file name?"... What did You try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the input file name: ");
        String newfile = sc.nextLine() + ".txt";
}
```

the String newfile will always have the file type extension...
hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're wanting to just modify a filename, or read in a file. I assumed the second one.

```
//Get filename
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the input file name: ");
String filename = sc.nextLine();
sc.close();

//Read file into StringBuilder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
  sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```